# como conectar VM com mysql em uma outra VM com PHP/Apache?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, virtualhost, máquina-virtual

Boa noite, gente. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em php/mysql afim de aprimorar meus conhecimentos na área. Sabendo disso, preciso agora simular um servidor, fazendo os seguintes passos:

1° Criar três máquinas virtuais(com o S.O ubuntu, no virtual box) cada uma com uma função distinta sendo, respectivamente, o primeiro com o banco de dados, o segundo com os códigos php e o terceiro como o cliente/usuário final que irá acessar normalmente o site/sistema criado.
a conexão seria feita desta maneira : 1°Banco > 2°PHP > 3° Cliente (um "encadeado" ao outro).
Resultado:
Já consegui instalar o mysql na primeira máquina e colocar os códigos na 2°. O problema que não encontrei solução, ainda, é de fazer a conexão da 3° máquina(cliente) com a 2°(do php).

Sugestões?

Comment: Rogério, seja bem vindo. Olhe te recomendo a fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), sua pergunta está [fora do escopo da comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) pois trata-se de configuração de um **Software** que não tem haver com **Programação**, mas fazendo uma pesquisa no **Google** você encontra vários tutoriais ensinando a configurar acesso a **VM** via rede.

Comment: Veja esses artigos: [VirtualBox:Criando uma rede interna entre Host e VMs com ips estáticos](http://marlonpatrick.info/pt-br/2012/06/03/virtualbox-criando-uma-rede-interna-entre-host-e-vms/), [Aprenda a Configurar o VirtualBox para Simular uma Rede de Computadores com Máquinas Virtuais](https://salimaouar.com.br/configuracao-virtualbox-simular-rede-computadores-maquinas-virtuais).

Comment: Ok, obrigado! e desculpe por isso, sou novo aqui..